# Show the copy menu on a view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show the ios copy button on a view and handle the click on a custom function. I tried to display the button with this code but nothing is appearing.

```
let menu = UIMenuController.shared
                    if !menu.isMenuVisible {
                        menu.setTargetRect(paragraphTableViewCell.bounds, in: paragraphTableViewCell)
                        menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
                    }
```

EDIT:

I got this errors

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call **canBecomeFirstResponder** In your class.

And override **canPerformAction** then add your appropriate option as **UIMenuItem**

```
func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(self.cut) {
        return false
    }
    else if action == #selector(self.copy) {
        return true
    }
    else if action == #selector(self.paste) {
        return false
    }
    else if action == #selector(self.select) || action == #selector(self.selectAll) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }

}



override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {

}
```

Finally you should pass **UIView** object

```
menu.setTargetRect(paragraphTableViewCell.bounds, in: paragraphTableViewCell.contentView)
```

Because its required

```
- (void)setTargetRect:(CGRect)targetRect inView:(UIView *)targetView;
```

Comment: Thank you. I got an error when pasting your code, I updated the question.